# Identify entry from different keypads if(e.Keycode)

Tags: c#, mapping, keypad

I'm in the process of making a game in C# for 2 players, each player has its own keypad. I use the following code for identifying which key is pressed but I don't know from which keypad it comes from and I need to identify which key is pressed from which keypad.

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Divide) 
{

     //code

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

If you use 2 usb keypads, Windows key events will be invoke without "keypad ID" parameter and there's no way to check who click.

I would suggest you set different keys on each players.

Hope I help you.

Comment: Thank you for replying, each keypad is for registering the number of points you did, so cant use a different set of keys for each player.